# how to approch this object loading problem with javascript and HTML

Tags: javascript, html

I am working on a web application, I am just using javascript at the moment. The problem that I am trying to solve is that I have three different objects and only one HTML page. Based on the user click event, I want the objects for the chosen category to be loaded and displayed on the same page. For example, let's say the user is at the home page, if they click on category A from the navigation bar, the page will be loaded first and then the script will load the objects to the data structure. Finally, display them to the javascript generated HTML containers. The same thing should happen with a different category after the User click Event is fired. To be more precise I want to be able to reuse the HTML page for different objects without having to create a page for each category.

I already have created the code that does all of the data loading and HTML generation for the n objects I want to load. The code works fine when I am at the object's page but if the event is fired from another page nothing seems to happen. I am guessing this has to do with page loading timing.

I have posted the complete code of the part that I am working on.

```
var dataController = (function() {
  var JSONurls = {
    bags: "../JSON/bags.json",
    bc: "../JSON/briefcases.json",
    belts: "../JSON/belts.json",
    accs: "../JSON/accs.json",
  };

  ProductObj = function(name, des, colors, price, pics, type, ID) {
    this.name = name;
    this.description = des;
    this.colors = colors;
    this.price = price;
    this.pics = pics;
    this.type = type;
    this.ID = ID;
  };

  var dataStruc = {
    allProducts: {
      bags: [],
      briefcases: [],
      belts: [],
      accessories: [],
    },
  };

  return {
    addProd: function(obj) {
      var newProd, ID;

      if (dataStruc.allProducts[obj.type].length > 0) {
        ID =
          dataStruc.allProducts[obj.type][
            dataStruc.allProducts[obj.type].length - 1
          ].ID + 1;
      } else {
        ID = 0;
      }

      newProd = new ProductObj(
        obj.name,
        obj.description,
        obj.colors,
        obj.price,
        obj.pics,
        obj.type,
        obj.ID
      );

      dataStruc.allProducts[obj.type].push(newProd);

      return newProd;
    },

    getDataStruct: function() {
      return dataStruc;
    },

    getJsonUrls: function() {
      return JSONurls;
    },

    loadJSON: function(url, cat, callback) {
      var requestURL, request, JsonObj;

      requestURL = url;

      request = new XMLHttpRequest();

      request.open("GET", requestURL);

      request.responseType = "text";

      request.send();

      request.onload = function() {
        JsonObj = JSON.parse(request.response);

        dataStruc.allProducts[cat] = JsonObj[cat];

        callback(cat);
      };
    },
  };
})();

var UIcontroller = (function() {
  var DomStrings = {
    shopCatg: ".shop-catg",
    productCont: ".product-container",
  };

  //public methods
  return {
    // function display the object based on the category based on the event target

    displayObjectToPage: function(cat) {
      var deafultHtml;

      // 1. loop over the product category

      dataController.getDataStruct().allProducts[cat].forEach(function(cur) {
        deafultHtml =
          '<div class="col-lg-4 col-md-6 col-sm-10">' +
          '<img class="img-fluid" src="../img/' +
          cur.type +
          "/" +
          cur.pics[0] +
          '.jpg">' +
          '<h6 class="text-center">' +
          cur.name +
          "</h6>" +
          '<div class="text-center text-muted">' +
          cur.price +
          "</div>" +
          "</div>";

        document
          .querySelector(DomStrings.productCont)
          .insertAdjacentHTML("beforeend", deafultHtml);
      });
    },

    getDomStrings: function() {
      return DomStrings;
    },
  };
})();

var mainController = (function(UIctrl, dataCrtl) {
  var setUpEvents = function() {
    var doneLoading = false;

    var DOM = UIctrl.getDomStrings();

    document.querySelector(DOM.shopCatg).addEventListener("click", function() {
      InitializeData(event, function(cat) {
        UIcontroller.displayObjectToPage(cat);
      });
    });
  };

  InitializeData = function(event, callback) {
    var category = event.target.textContent;

    if (event.target.textContent === "bags") {
      dataController.loadJSON(
        dataController.getJsonUrls().bags,
        category,
        callback
      );
    } else if (event.target.textContent === "briefcases") {
      dataController.loadJSON(dataController.getJsonUrls().bags, "briefcases");
    } else if (event.target.textContent === "belts") {
      dataController.loadJSON(dataController.getJsonUrls().bags, "belts");
    } else {
      dataController.loadJSON(dataController.getJsonUrls().bags, "accs");
    }
  };

  displayObject = function() {};
  return {
    init: function() {
      setUpEvents();
    },
  };
})(UIcontroller, dataController);

mainController.init();
```

Comment: This type of thing is a perfect use case for a tool like React/Vue/Svelte that provide a way of managing state, data flow, and updates to the DOM. You can do it in pure javascript, of course, but there's enough an affinity here that it's worth mentioning. Your code would be really easy to port over to React; you've organized it well.

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion unfortunately at the moment I am still learning. I haven't made the jump to JS frameworks.  what would you recommend as a possible approach to take using javascript? you think it would be worth it to create a page for each category and automatically load the objects on page load without passing any parameters that point at which category was selected.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure, but I noticed this potential issue:

```
request.send();
request.onload = function() {
  // ...
}
```

I believe when you call `send`, the request should start asynchronously. If the request comes back before `onload` is assigned, you might be seeing it get skipped. I haven't used XHR directly in years, though.

Normally you'd want to add the `onload` callback *before* calling `send()` to avoid this issue.

---

I also just noticed that you're missing the `event` in the arguments of the callback function here:

```
                                                                       ▽
document.querySelector(DOM.shopCatg).addEventListener("click", function() {
                 ▽ event is undefined
  InitializeData(event, function(cat) {
    UIcontroller.displayObjectToPage(cat);
  });
});
```